# Cant get my Cache simulator to run correctly

Tags: java, caching

So I have been trying to get a program that will simulate how a LRU replacement policy on a simple cache but for some reason when I input the numbers im trying to enter into the reference string for the cache to implement, it only displays the first number entered and displays 0s after that. I need it to add numbers into the cache using the LRU replacement policy that we are learning in class.

Here is my code

`

```
package cacheProject;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class cacheProject {

   private int numBlocks;
   private int setAssoc;
   private String replacementPolicy;
   public cacheProject(int numBlocks, int setAssoc, String replacementPolicy) {
       this.numBlocks = numBlocks;
       this.setAssoc = setAssoc;
       this.replacementPolicy = replacementPolicy;
   }
   public void simulate(int[] references) {
       int missRate = 0;
       int hits = 0;
       int[] cache = new int[numBlocks];
       for (int i = 0; i < references.length; i++) {
           int block = references[i];
           // check if block is in cache
           boolean inCache = false;
           for (int j = 0; j < cache.length; j++) {
               if (cache[j] == block) {
                   inCache = true;
                   hits++;
                   break;
               }
           }
           // if not in cache, add it
           if (!inCache) {
               missRate++;
               // if cache is full, remove LRU block
               if (cache[numBlocks - 1] != 0) {
                   int lruBlock = findLRUBlock(cache);
                   cache[lruBlock] = 0;
               }
               // add new block to cache
               for (int j = 0; j < cache.length; j++) {
                   if (cache[j] == 0) {
                       cache[j] = block;
                       break;
                   }
               }
           }
       }
       System.out.println("Miss rate: " + (double) missRate / references.length);
       System.out.println("Hits: " + hits);
       System.out.println("Cache contents:");
       for (int i = 0; i < cache.length; i++) {
           System.out.print(cache[i] + " ");
       }
       System.out.println();
   }
   public int findLRUBlock(int[] cache) {
       if (replacementPolicy.equals("LRU")) {
           int lruBlock = 0;
           int lruTime = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
           for (int i = 0; i < cache.length; i++) {
               int time = 0;
               for (int j = 0; j < cache.length; j++) {
                   if (cache[i] == cache[j]) {
                       time++;
                   }
               }
               if (time < lruTime) {
                   lruBlock = i;
                   lruTime = time;
               }
           }
           return lruBlock;
       }
       return -1;
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.print("Enter number of cache blocks: ");
       int numBlocks = in.nextInt();
       System.out.print("Enter set associativity (1=direct mapped, 2=2-way, 4=4-way): ");
       int setAssoc = in.nextInt();
       System.out.print("Enter replacement policy (FIFO or LRU): ");
       String replacementPolicy = in.next();
       cacheProject cache = new cacheProject(numBlocks, setAssoc, replacementPolicy);
       System.out.println("Enter reference string:");
       String input = in.next();
       String[] references = input.split(" ");
       int[] refs = new int[references.length];
       for (int i = 0; i < references.length; i++) {
           refs[i] = Integer.parseInt(references[i]);
       }
       cache.simulate(refs);
   }
}
```

`

Here is the output

Enter number of cache blocks: 5
Enter set associativity (1=direct mapped, 2=2-way, 4=4-way): 1
Enter replacement policy (FIFO or LRU): LRU
Enter reference string:
3 4 3 5 4 3 5
Miss rate: 1.0
Hits: 0
Cache contents:
3 0 0 0 0

What I am expecting is

Enter number of cache blocks: 5
Enter set associativity (1=direct mapped, 2=2-way, 4=4-way): 1
Enter replacement policy (FIFO or LRU): LRU
Enter reference string:
3 4 3 5 4
Miss rate: 1.0
Hits: 0
Cache contents:
3 4 3 5 4

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem , you need to read the line, you input.nextLine() instead of next().
Also you must create a second object of type scanner for the nextLine() method.
See Code below

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.print("Enter cache blocks: ");
   int blockNum = in.nextInt();
   System.out.print("Enter set associativity (1=direct mapped, 2=2-way, 4=4-way): ");
   int setAssoc = in.nextInt();
   System.out.print("Enter replacement policy (FIFO or LRU): ");
   String replacementPolicy = in.next();
   Simulate cache = new Simulate(blockNum, setAssoc, replacementPolicy);
   System.out.println("Enter reference string:");
   Scanner inRef = new Scanner(System.in);
   String input = inRef.nextLine();
   String[] references = input.trim().split(" ");
   System.out.println(input);
   int[] refs = new int[references.length];
   for (int i = 0; i < references.length; i++) {
       refs[i] = Integer.parseInt(references[i]);
   }
   cache.simulate(refs);
```

}